# How to text-to-speech a PHP table

Tags: javascript, php, text-to-speech

I'm working on a project where I have a table containing a list of students, I want my web-app to "say" their name and last names one by one, the same as when a teacher is marking who's present or not.

I dont know if the technology to go to in this situation is Javascript or PHP, although it looks like Javascript might be easier.

Here is the code for the table display, and I thank you all in advance :

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_GET['datepick']) & isset($_GET['classpick'])) {
        $datepicked = $_GET['datepick'];
        $matierepicked =  $_GET['classpick'];
        $viewab = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM absence,etudiant WHERE absence.date = ? AND absence.matiere = ? AND (absence.etudiant_ID = etudiant.etudiant_ID)");
        $viewab->execute(array($datepicked, $matierepicked));

        if ($viewab->rowCount()!=0){


        echo("<table class='table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered table-striped' style='background-color: white'>");
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th style='background-color: grey'> Nom </th>";
        echo "<th style='background-color: grey'>Prenom </th>";
        echo "<th style='background-color: grey'>Matiere</th>";
        echo "<th style='background-color: grey'>Date</th>";
        echo "<th style='background-color: grey'>Total des heures absentées</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        while ($row = $viewab->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Nom'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Prenom'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['matiere'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Nb_absences'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo("</table>"); }
```

Comment: JS has an (experimental) feature [SpeechSynthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis) which could be used for this.

Comment: https://dev.to/asaoluelijah/text-to-speech-in-3-lines-of-javascript-b8h

Comment: @Reyno Thanks I'll take a look and see if it helps

Comment: to add to the other commentss here is the offical W3C Web Speech API document  -> https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/#introduction which also might prove usefull

Comment: be aware tho if you want to support IE that you need a polyfill -> https://www.google.com/search?q=speechsynthesis+polyfill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript will be easier, for example:

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
msg.text = "Hello World";
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

Comment: Should I take every row's name and last name and concatenate them into that msg variable then use the speak function on it ? Do you think that would be a good way to do it ?

Comment: Yes you can put all the rows in one variable and do the speak or speak on every rows.

Comment: this is the simplest wat to generate speech

Answer (score 1):

You could just parse your table and add the names to the [SpeechSynthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis).

Below is a more advanced example using the [end event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/end_event).

```js
// Get HTML elements
const persons = document.querySelectorAll('.person-table tbody tr');
const btn = document.querySelector('.speak-btn');

// Speak function
const speak = (msg) => {
  const synth = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  synth.text = msg;
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(synth);
}

// Pronounce names
const pronounceNames = (persons) => {
  for(const person of persons) {
    const [name, lastname] = person.children;
    const fullname = `${name.textContent} ${lastname.textContent}`;
    
    speak(fullname);
  }
}

// Add click event
btn.addEventListener('click', () => pronounceNames(persons));
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' />

<table class='person-table table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered table-striped'>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th>      <th>Lastname</th> <th>Gender</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Elis</td>      <td>Simmons</td>  <td>F</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dhruv</td>     <td>Marshall</td> <td>M</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Millicent</td> <td>Hanson</td>   <td>F</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ivy</td>       <td>Reyes</td>    <td>F</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Benjamin</td>  <td>Rahman</td>   <td>M</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type='button' class='speak-btn btn btn-primary'>Speak</button>
```

**More interactive solution**

```js
// Get HTML elements
const persons = document.querySelectorAll('.person-table tbody tr');
const btn = document.querySelector('.speak-btn');

// Create `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` instance
const synth = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

// Current person in the loop
let currentPerson = 0;

// Speak function
const speak = (msg) => {
  synth.text = msg;
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(synth);
}

// Create queue of names
const createQueue = (persons) => {
  const queue = new Map();
  
  // Get fullname and add it to the queue
  for(const person of persons) {
    const [name, lastname] = person.children;
    const fullname = `${name.textContent} ${lastname.textContent}`;
    
    queue.set(person, fullname);
  }
  
  return queue;
}

const queue = createQueue(persons);

// Pronounce names
const pronounceNames = () => {
  const person = persons[currentPerson];
  
  // Pronounce name
  if(queue.has(person)) {
    const name = queue.get(person);
    speak(name);

    person.classList.add('highlight');
  }
}

const checkQueue = () => {
  // Increase counter
  currentPerson++;

  // Remove highlight class
  for(const person of persons) {
    person.classList.remove('highlight');
  }
   
  // Check if the queue is empty
  if(currentPerson <= queue.size - 1) {
    pronounceNames();
  }else{
    // Reset for next button press
    currentPerson = 0;
    console.log('Finished...');
  }
};

// Add click event
btn.addEventListener('click', pronounceNames);

// Add ending event
synth.addEventListener('end', checkQueue);
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' />

<table class='person-table table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered table-striped'>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th>      <th>Lastname</th> <th>Gender</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Elis</td>      <td>Simmons</td>  <td>F</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dhruv</td>     <td>Marshall</td> <td>M</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Millicent</td> <td>Hanson</td>   <td>F</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ivy</td>       <td>Reyes</td>    <td>F</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Benjamin</td>  <td>Rahman</td>   <td>M</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type='button' class='speak-btn btn btn-primary'>Speak</button>
```